Proving $a_{n} = \lfloor \sqrt{2n} + \frac{1}{2} \rfloor$ for sequence $1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ...$ where positive integer $k$ is repeated $k$ times.
Rosen [ Discrete Math ] Exercise 28 : Proving $a_{n} = \lfloor \sqrt{2n} + \frac{1}{2} \rfloor$ for sequence $1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ...$ where positive integer $k$ is repeated $k$ times.
A Solution is given , though I do not understand the 2 parts of the solution/proof for this problem that I found in the Discrete Math Rosen textbook.

1st part underlined:

Why is it that to find $k$ as a function of $n$, we must find the
smallest $k$ such that $k(k + 1)/2 \geq n$?

Also, why is it that after we find that $k$ must be at least $(-1 +   
   \sqrt{1 + 8n})/2$, that $k = \lceil (-1 + \sqrt{1 + 8n})/2 \rceil$?


2nd part underlined:
This part is essentially trying to show how $\lceil (-1 + \sqrt{1 + 8n})/2 \rceil = \lceil \frac{-1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + 2n} \rceil$ is same as $\lfloor \sqrt{2n} + \frac{1}{2} \rfloor$.
I do not understand their reasoning for why it is impossible for $\sqrt{2n} \leq m + \frac{1}{2}$ while $\sqrt{2n + \frac{1}{4}} > m + \frac{1}{2}$, and why we are considering this case here in our proof in the first place?
Kindly please help me in understanding this particular proof. Thank you.
EDIT: Just to clarify about exercise 48 and 49 mentioned in the proof:
Confusion on floor and ceiling function proof question.

By the author's reasoning, we have $$a_n\leq k\iff k(k+1)/2\geq n$$
Our goal is to determine $a_n=k$ in terms of $n$. If we fix $n$ and we find the smallest $k'$ with $k'(k'+1)/2\geq n$ by the above equivalence we will have that $a_n\leq k'$.
If it was the case that $a_n<k'$ we would have $a_n\leq k'-1$ and so $(k'-1)((k'-1)+1)/2\geq n$, contradicting the minimality of $k'$, so we must have that $a_n=k'$.
To find this $k'$ we notice that $$k(k+1)/2\geq n\iff k^2+k-2n\geq 0\iff k\geq (-1+\sqrt{1+8n})/2$$
where the last equivalence is true because we are only considering non-negative values of $k$.
Thus, the minimal $k$ verifying the condition will be the smallest integer bigger than $(-1+\sqrt{1+8n})/2$, that is, $\lceil (-1+\sqrt{1+8n})/2 \rceil$.
As for the second part, the author notices that $$\lceil (-1+\sqrt{1+8n})/2 \rceil=\bigg\lceil -\dfrac{1}{2}+\sqrt{1/4+2n}\bigg\rceil$$
Using the Exercise $49$ of the book, we have that $\bigg\lceil -\dfrac{1}{2}+\sqrt{1/4+2n}\bigg\rceil$ is the closest integer to $\sqrt{2n+1/4}$.
Now, we wish to prove that this integer is also the closest to $\sqrt{2n}$, because we know by Exercise $48$ that it is equal to $\lfloor \sqrt{2n}+1/2\rfloor$, as desired.
In order to do that, we show that it is impossible to have $\sqrt{2n}\leq m+1/2$ and $\sqrt{2n+1/4}>m+1/2$ for some integer $m$: this way the fractional parts of $\sqrt{2n}$ and $\sqrt{2n+1/4}$ are either both bigger than $1/2$ or both smaller than $1/2$, which implies that they share the same closest integer.
If $\sqrt{2n}\leq m+1/2$ and $\sqrt{2n+1/4}>m+1/2$, squaring both inequalities we get $$2n\leq m^2+m+1/4, \quad 2n> m^2+m$$
or in other words, $$2n\in (m^2+m,m^2+m+1/4]$$
Given that $2n$ and $m^2+m$ are integers this is not possible ($2n$ would have non-zero fractional part).
Thus, we have that the closest integer to $\sqrt{2n+1/4}$ is the same as the closest to $\sqrt{2n}$, which means that $$a_n=\left\lfloor \sqrt{2n}+1/2\right\rfloor $$

Hey I just edited the question to clarify about the exercises 48 & 49 mentioned in the proof. Not sure if that would further help here.

Also, I'm confused on how showing it's "impossible to have $\sqrt{2n}\leq m+1/2$ and $\sqrt{2n+1/4}>m+1/2$ for some integer $m$" means that "this way the fractional parts of $\sqrt{2n}$ and $\sqrt{2n+1/4}$ are either both bigger than $1/2$ or both smaller than $1/2$, which implies that they share the same closest integer"... isn't the negation of this $\sqrt{2n} > m+1/2$ OR $\sqrt{2n+1/4} \leq m+1/2$ for some integer $m$.

Also, just to be clear it's $\lfloor \sqrt{2n} + \frac{1}{2} \rfloor$, not $\lfloor \sqrt{2n + \frac{1}{2} } \rfloor$

Hey man did you see my followup questions/clarifications in the comments?

Here's a different approach,
Let $k$ be a positive integer. What is the first index $n$ such that $a_n=k$? To answer this, let's look at a few values of the sequence,
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$
Now the indeces where this happens are $1,2,4,7,11,...$ Do you see a pattern? If we take the difference between each consecutive term we see $1,2,3,4...$ this is just an arithmetic sequence! If we denote the first sequence by $(b_n)$ and the second by $(d_n)=(b_{n+1}-b_n)$ Then our result becomes
$$d_n=b_{n+1}-b_n=n$$
Summing the telescoping series or induction is enough to prove that $$b_n=1+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
Remember that $b_n$ is defined as the first index such that $a_{b_n}=n$ therefore using the definition of $a_n$ we should have $$a\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+i\right)=n\quad\forall \;1\le i\le n$$
Now this is just a matter of solving for $a_n$. In other words solving for $n$ in terms of $k$ in this inequality, $$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1\le k \le \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n$$
You can easily check that
$$\frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+8k }}{2} \leq n \leq \frac{
1+ \sqrt{ 8k-7}}{2}$$
and since the length of this interval is
$$\begin{align*}
&\frac{1+ \sqrt{8k-7}}{2}-\frac{-1+ \sqrt{8k+1}}{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{8k-7} - \sqrt{8k+1}\right) +1\\
&= \frac{-4}{\sqrt{1 + 8k} + \sqrt{-7 + 8k}}+1\le 1
\end{align*}$$ because $k\ge 1$. We have
$$n=\left\lfloor \frac{1+ \sqrt{8k-7}}{2}\right\rfloor$$
In other words
$$a_n=\left\lfloor \frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2n-\frac{7}{4}}\right\rfloor$$
